# Cayley-Hamilton theorem-eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cayley-hamilton

I am studying and doing exercises about the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem but I am having difficulties to understand this question:

I have the matrix $A$ as

\begin{bmatrix}
 2&1\\
1&2\\
\end{bmatrix}

I found the characteristic equation which is : $\lambda^2-4\lambda+3=0$ and eigenvalues of $\lambda=1$ and  and $\lambda=3$

Then to apply Cayley-Hamilton I replaced the $\lambda$ in the characteristic equeation by A and obtained:

$A^2-4A+3=0$ and then I calculated matrix $A^2$ and verify that the Cayley-Hamilton is verified since,

$$
A^2-4A+3I=\begin{bmatrix}
5&4\\
4&5\\
\end{bmatrix}
-
4\begin{bmatrix}
2&1\\
1&2\\
\end{bmatrix}
+
3\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Considering the matrices $A,A^2,0$ the 2x2 zero matrix  and $I$ the identity matrix and all linear combinations of them, so that they form a vector space.

How can I use the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem to give basis for this vector space?

I do not understand this part, should I found the eigenvectors for matrices $A,A^2,0$ and $I$?

Can anyone help on this I do not understand how Cayley-Hamilton can give a basis for this vector.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The matrices $I$ and $A$ are linearly independent.  However, the matrices $I,A,A^2$ are **not** linearly independent.

Comment: So because they are linearly independent ( they only have the trivial solution x=y=0) the basis are the vector (2,1),(1,2)(1,0) and (0,1) ?

Comment: What?  No.  Our vector space consists of square matrices, not column vectors.  The basis should consists of square matrices, not column-vectors.  One possible basis is $\{I,A\}$.

Comment: So I was checking and did:  -8x-4y=0,-4x-8y=0,3x+0y=0,0x+y=0  corresponding to matrix A and I multiplied by the coefficients -4 and 3 ( A^2-4A+12I) with solutions x=y=0 (linearly independent) and then 5x+4y=0,4x+5y=0,-8x-4y=0,-4x-8y=0,3x+0y=0,0x+y=0 with no trivial solutions so they are linearly dependent. Am I doing something wrong? can you help me on this? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I understood now. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, sorry to ask again, but just to clarify:

you are saying that {A,I} is a possible basis because $\left(\begin{array}{cc|cccc}
  2 & 1  &  0\\
  1    & 0 & 0        \\
1 & 0  &  0\\
2 & 1  &  0\\
 \end{array}\right)$ x=y=0 Lin.Indp so they form a basis. However {I,A,$A^2$}= $\left(\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
  5 & 2  & 1 &  0\\
  4    & 1 & 0& 0        \\
4 & 2 & 0 &  0\\
5 & 1 & 1 &  0\\
 \end{array}\right)$ no trivial solution no lin.indp then don't form a basis.

Comment: Should I also say the other combinations such as: {A,$A^2$} and {$A^2,I$} also can be a basis as: in both x=y=0? Or Am I completly wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea. You don't need to say the other combinations